# z-index and CSS positioning not working

Tags: layout, position, css-position, z-index

I have a sidebar with a vertical nav menu and need to get the hover sub menu to flost to the left of the sidebar, however upon hover the submenu is cut off by the edge of the sidebar...how do I go about bringing this to the top?

i have tried using z-index' and changing the positioning but i'm not sure which element to set which position.

the side bar needs to be fixed position due to the layout.

here is a jsfiddle of the basic layout https://jsfiddle.net/Lnhrbouo/

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been at this for hours now.

Thanks.

```
<div class="sideBar">
<div id="side-wrap" class="container">
    <div id="wrapper-side">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo-shot.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="a">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="test7.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="grid.php">Solutions <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="accounting.php">Accounting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="cloud.php">Cloud Accounting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="tax.php">Tax</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="business.php">Business Planning</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="future.php">Planning Your Future</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size: 12px;"></i></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="staff.php">Staff</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="values.php">Our Values</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="newsletter">
             <h1>NEWSLETTER</h1> 
            <div id='content'>
                <div id="hidden-content"> <span class="signup">Sign Up Today</span> 
                    <input class="side-mail" type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="Enter your email here">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='button'>
                <sctrong>
                    <img src="images/more-banner.png" />
                    </strong>
            </div>
            <script>

            </script>
        </div>
        <div id="barFoot">
            <p>© 2013 address goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="centre">
        <div class="visibleArea">
            <div id="header-text">
                <p class="call-top"><span class="hide-call">CALL TODAY     </span>
                    <span="small-call"><strong>00000</strong> | <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i></a>
                        </span>
                        <div id="top2">
                            <div class="section group">
                                <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                                    <img src="images/logo-round.PNG" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span_1_of_2 split">
                                    <div id="ftp-ico">  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i></a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div id="show-number">CALL TODAY</span>
                                        <span="small-call">    <strong>000000</strong>

                                    </div>
                                    <div id="resp-newsletter">
                                        <input class="side-mail split-news" type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="Sign up for our newsletter">
                                        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button split-side">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="full" style="background:#456789;">
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="images/ggow.PNG" />
            <img src="images/dome.PNG" />
            <img src="images/reflect.PNG" />
            <img src="images/purple.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside .sideBar class change

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

to

```
overflow: visible;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnhrbouo/2/